# How to keep Typescript from prefering global types over imports

Tags: typescript

So, for my Typescript code I wanted to introduce an interface called `Account` which contains account-related info, obviously.

So far, this has resided in "Account.d.ts" and it has worked quite fine, but I just recently found out that the .d.ts is not the way to go exactly when it comes to typescript, and I wanted to change it to an exported interface in a proper "Account.ts" class.

So, this is what it looks like now:

```
export default interface Account {
    userName: string;
    email: string;
    profilePicturePath: string;
    lastAccessedAt: Date;
    id: string;
}
```

So far so good. Previously, I also had the problem that there is another type called "Account", defined in a file called `lib.dom.d.ts`, which was constantly picked up by Typescript and via declaration merging messed with my type.

Now, with my new new Account.ts, this is what I did:

```
import Account from "Definitions/Account";

interface IProps {
    account: Account;
}
```

But this does not work. Typescript still picks up the `Account` in `lib.dom.d.ts` as the proper Account type here, and I can't figure out how I can make Typescript recognize which one is the proper one. If possible, I would just like to ignore this external definition which does not have anything to do with my code at all.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with your IDE due to caching behavior. You should be able to clear the cache in your IDE by restarting the TypeScript language server.

### Visual Studio Code

- Open the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P)
- Run command **TypeScript: Restart TS server**

### TSConfig

You could also try modifying your TypeScript configuration to exclude type definitions for certain packages:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

#### Only use types from the specified paths

```js
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "typeRoots" : ["./typings"]
   }
}
```

#### Only use types from the specified packages

```js
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "types" : ["node", "lodash", "express"]
   }
}
```

#### Exclude all external packages

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": { /* ... */ },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```